# Google Docs Drawings and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, google-docs

I am wondering how does SVG work in IE with Google Docs Drawings?

Is it flash?

Could you please point me to the library they use to add SVG support to IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Docs Drawings: They seem to use VML in IE instead of SVG.

Adding SVG Support to IE: take a look at this SO thread: [How to make SVG work with IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie)

There are several libraries which use VML in Internet Explorer:

- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [Ample SDK](http://www.amplesdk.com/)
- [DojoX GFX](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-5-dojox/dojox-gfx)

And libs using flash:

- [Google svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)