# svg is not working with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to open this site in IE:

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/interactive-svg-map

but somehow it is not showing the SVG.

how do I get it to work with IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SVG work with IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find that your page is  not working in ASV, and is working in Chrome (it does appear to be), I would recommend you target [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) instead. To  use it, install and add the following meta tag to the head of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

Answer (score 2):

IE does not support SVG (All versions prior to 9)
IE 9 **will* support SVG, but untill then you can find a [plugin for your IE](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/mainframed.html)

Comment: could have been programming related. If not, it would have been moved to SuperUser, don't worry. See e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie

Answer (score 0):

the web application needs a tag like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IE below version 9 are not supporting the SVG component ,IE 8 and below support VML but to make SVG working in a recent version of IE , you can just enter below code in your head of html file

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>

<style>
 .chromeFrameInstallDefaultStyle {
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  width: 800px; /* default is 800px */
  height: 80%; /* default is 800px */
  border: 5px solid blue;
  right:100px;
  bottom:100px;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
 }
</style>

<div id="prompt">
  <!-- if IE without GCF, prompt goes here -->
</div>

<script>
    // The conditional ensures that this code will only execute in IE,
    // Therefore we can use the IE-specific attachEvent without worry
    window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
        CFInstall.check({
            mode: "inline", // the default
            node: "prompt"
        });
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

This will ask user to install the google frame on the IE . Just take few minutes . After that all html5 components as well SVG components work . "MOSTLY"