# how to display inlinesvg in ie8

Tags: jquery, html, svg

how can i display this in ie8, this is an inlinesvg polygons with links, is there a jQuery script or something

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="643px"
     height="735px" viewBox="0 0 643 735" enable-background="new 0 0 643 735" xml:space="preserve">

<a xlink:href="img/interactive/pietraCT/01.jpg" title="zobacz rzut 12 piętra" class="conceptBoxFloor">
    <g id="ct_12">
        <polygon  points="153,286.5 194.667,254.5 194.481,247.497 295.5,173 301.75,175.313 379.667,118.5 
            383.667,121.167 395.334,113.833 501.938,219 501.938,245.667 394.667,147.667 384.333,153.333 379.667,151.667 302.25,205.667 
            296.667,204.667 194.074,276.472 194,280 153,308.25  "/>
    </g>
</a>
<a xlink:href="img/interactive/pietraCT/01.jpg" title="zobacz rzut 13 piętra" class="conceptBoxFloor">
    <g id="ct_13">
        <polygon  points="153,255.5 194.25,222.5 194.25,213.813 294,133.75 301.5,138.75 379.75,76.75 
            384.5,79.25 393.501,71.667 501.938,184.333 501.375,211.25 394.25,105 384,111.75 379.75,108.75 302.25,167.5 295,163.625 
            194.25,239.75 194.481,247.497 153,278.875   "/>
    </g>
</a>
<a xlink:href="img/interactive/pietraCT/01.jpg" title="zobacz rzut 14 piętra" class="conceptBoxFloor">
    <g id="ct_14">
        <polygon  points="153,224 192.25,189.667 192.125,177.875 292.5,92 302,98.833 380,31.667 384,35.167 
            394.334,26.5 501.938,149 501.938,175 394.5,61.333 383.5,68.667 381,66.5 301.167,131 293.5,125.5 194,205 194.25,216.125 
            153.083,248.875     "/>
    </g>
</a>

</svg>
```

do help me pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SVG work with IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427051/how-to-make-svg-work-with-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer version 8 did not support SVG natively. You need to upgrade to IE9, or use something like [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) which provides support for older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

I was playing around with this a few months back. Maybe you'll find this useful - http://keith-wood.name/svg.html